# Forwarding Tomcat requests

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I have a domain with a mixture of PHP and Tomcat running in nginx. This is how it looks.
I have a domain *example.com* on this site I have a Wordpress installation. This is no problem at all.
Now what I want is when you navigate to *example.com/backend* that it gets forwarded to Tomcat.

For now I still have a default installation and every new webapp I install is needed to be placed in /tomcatinstallationfolder/webapps. I want to be able to put these apps in the backend directory in the docroot of my site. How do I need to configure Tomcat in order to accomplish this?

This is the configuration for forwarding requests to Tomcat. Again this is the default installation from the binary package.

```
server {
    listen          80 default_server;
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     www.example.com example.com;
    root            /var/www;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate certificates/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key certificates/example.com.key;

    include         error_pages;
    include         php_config;

    location /backend {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwar$
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things to respond to here.

Generally, it is a bad idea to overlap the locations that Tomcat and the reverse proxy are using to serve content. Therefore, if your "backend" directory is `/var/www/backend` then I'd strongly recommend moving the `/backend` directory somewhere else such as `/var/tomcat/webapps`. The reason for this is security. Unless you get the configuration exactly right, you can end up with the reverse proxy serving content it shouldn't such as the source code of JSPs or the contents of web.xml.

Next, you are changing the content path of your applications in the proxy. This is going to cause all sorts of subtle problems. What I mean by this is a request to example.com/backend/myapp is going to get routed to localhost:8080/myapp. At the reverse proxy the context path is `/backend/myapp` but in Tomcat the context path is `/myapp`. Changing the context path like this will break all sorts of things including redirects, links but dynamically in the app, cookie paths to name the first few that come to mind. You can work around these issues in the reverse proxy but it is a huge pain. It would be much better to keep the context path the same.

With the above in mind, I recommend that you use the following settings:

1. Create `/var/tomcat/webapps`
2. Configure your Host's appBase (in server.xml) to be `/var/tomcat/webapps`
3. Deploy your WAR files and directories to `/var/tomcat/webapps`
4. Name your WARs backend#app1.war, backend#app2.war etc.
5. Modify your nginx config to use `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/backend`

Naming your WAR files this way will give them context paths of /backend/app1, /backend/app2 etc so the contenxt path used by Tomcat matches the one used by the client therefby avoiding all the issues associated with changing the context path.

Comment: I have created some kind of a working configuration, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. I can deploy new apps in    /var/www/backend/webapps. And Tomcat is installed in    /usr/local/tomcat. In the server.xml I changed the appBase to    /var/www/backend/webapps. So now I can deploy new apps using the backend directory in the docroot.